# Insert new rows and autofill with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to insert new rows if a particular condition is met. I want to drag the formula from the last row to the inserted row, but I am getting an error doing so. Below is my code:

```
  For i = 1 To diff
    MsgBox ("Difference is " & diff)

    With Sheet5.Rows(ModelLastRow.Row + 1)
       .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With

    insertRowRange = "C" & CStr((ModelLastRow.Row))

    pasteRowRange = "C" & CStr((ModelLastRow.Row + 1))
    Range("insertRowRange").AutoFill Destination:=Range("pasteRowRange")
  Next
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Are you trying to copy a single column or the whole row?

Comment: Define a table in excel and it will help you - you never have to drag the columns - just ensure that the you enter the formula in the first row and also ensure that column is empty in which the formula is entered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to copy a single cell down by one row. I'm going to assume that "ModelLastRow" is the single cell that you want to copy down. Every step of the loop, I offset ModelLastRow down by one to copy another row.

```
 Dim ModelNextRow As Range
 MsgBox ("Difference is " & diff)
 For i = 1 To diff

     Set ModelNextRow = Union(ModelLastRow, ModelLastRow.Offset(1, 0))
     ModelLastRow.AutoFill Destination:=ModelNextRow, Type:=xlFillDefault

     Set ModelLastRow = ModelLastRow.Offset(1, 0)
   Next

 End Sub
```

Hopefully this works for you, best of luck!